# recursive series mupad

Tags: recursion, series, mupad

I am trying to find the sum from n=1 to n=infinity of the following series:

```
A(n)=T/(n+1)*{a1*T^2*A(n-3)/((n-1)*n) + a2*T*A(n-2)/n + a3*A(n-1)}
```

with

```
A(-1)=A(0)=0
A(1)=T*a1/2
```

using mupad. Is it possible?

I tried the following code:

```
A := proc(n)
begin
  if(n<=0) then return(0) end_if:
  if(n=1) then return(a_1*T/2) end_if:
  return((T/(n+1))*(a_1*T^2*A(n-3)/((n-1)*n)
                    +a_2*T*A(n-2)/n
                    +a_3*A(n-1)))
end_proc:
```

which works fine for single elements of series A, however when i try to find even the partial sum for n=1..2:

```
sum(A(n),n=1..2)
```

mupad returns an error:

```
Error: Can't evaluate to boolean [_leequal];
during evaluation of 'A'
```

Is there a simpler approach to this problem?